# How to calculate reactance from an impedance analyzer circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, impedance, analysis, reactance

**Background**

I have an impedance analyzer that uses the below circuit:

[image: Impedance Analyzer Circuit]

[Source](https://reference.digilentinc.com/reference/add-ons/impedance-analyzer/reference-manual?_ga=2.102136961.1494699955.1564506457-27077327.1560894309)

One can measure impedance of the device under test (DUT) by using the following formulas:

`Z_load = Z_ref * (V_C1 - V_C2) / V_C2`

One can measure the phase by comparing the phase difference between V_C1 and V_C2.

Let's say positive phase is when V_C2 lags V_C1.

**Question**

How does one get from this information/formulas to be able to calculate resistance and reactance of the load?

Does one need to make assumptions about the load?  For example, in [this article](https://assets.testequity.com/te1/Documents/pdf/series-parallel-impedance-parameters-an.pdf) they assume series RC or RL, or parallel RC or RL circuits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the magnitude, Z, and phase angle, Theta,  of an impedance, then the reactance and resistance can be calculated as follows:

```
 reactance = Z*sin(theta)

 resistance = Z*cos(Theta)
```